# Unable to launch turtlebot3 waffle

Tags: ros-kinetic, turtlebot3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a turtlebot3 that was a burger that we are changing to a waffle. I followed the steps here: http://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/parts/controller/opencr10/#arduino-ide to set up the ide then followed the directions here: http://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/opencr_setup/#opencr-setup to upload the waffle code instead of the burger code.

Now, when we call up the tb3 using the command roslaunch turtlebot3_bringup turtlebot3_core.launch the turtlebot starts but fails.
Here is part of the terminal output:

[INFO] [1523234365.100797]: Connecting to /dev/ttyACM0 at 115200 baud
[ERROR] [1523234367.376107]: Creation of publisher failed: Checksum does not match: 427f77f85da38bc1aa3f65ffb673c94c,d537ed7b8d95065b6c83830430b93911

Then we have another error:
[ERROR] [1523234371.010786]: Creation of subscriber failed: 'module' object has no attribute 'Sound'

Further in the log after 'Calibration end' we get on repeat until I control-c,
[ERROR] [1523234372.879436]: Tried to publish before configured, topic id 125

I have tried using both the shell and the arduino ide methods for uploading the example code for the waffle and have gotten the same result. I have also now tried to revert it back to the burger using both methods and still receive this issue. I am using the launch files provided robotis on the pi.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/287938/unable-to-launch-turtlebot3-waffle/) by [hstusnick](https://answers.ros.org/users/33381/hstusnick/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-04-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi :)

I can't see your capture or something you type `terminal output`
And if you want to get an information about it, please visit [issue page](https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3/issues) in github turtlebot3 repo

---

Originally posted by [Darby Lim](https://answers.ros.org/users/30440/darby-lim/) with karma: 811 on 2018-04-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hstusnick](https://answers.ros.org/users/33381/hstusnick/) on 2018-04-08**:
Sorry these are pictures the pi had trouble opening a browser so I just took a picture instead. https://imgur.com/BueKGLA and https://imgur.com/oHBBlI8

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-04-09**:
@hstusnick please don't use an image to display text. Images are not searchable and people cannot copy and paste the text from the image. Please update your question with a copy and paste of the text.

**Comment by [Darby Lim](https://answers.ros.org/users/30440/darby-lim/) on 2018-04-09**:
Hi :) I checked your error messages. Next time copy and paste of the text would be help

Because of mismatch message types between turtlebot3_core.ino and turtlebot3_bringup, you have faced that problem.
Please check firmware version(the latest is v1.1.2) and download turtlebot3 code in github repo

**Comment by [hstusnick](https://answers.ros.org/users/33381/hstusnick/) on 2018-04-12**:
Thank you! It ended up that I was using 1.1.2 on my opencr board but the pi I was using with it was outdated so updating the turtlebot3 bringup files worked.